# Install chat widget in .pug file

Tags: javascript, widget, pug, chatbot, web-frontend

I need to install a chatbot widget on our website. that widget needs to call javascript and HTML tag. There is have no problem for me to install on the HTML environment.

But I have a problem installing it on one of my systems that using .pug for the front end.

the weird is its success on one of the pages. but when I try it on another page its failed.

This is the sample installation in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chatbot</title>
     <script src="https://unchatpkg.com/vue"></script>
     <script src="https://chatbot-prod.firebaseapp.com/plus-chatbotcomponent.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <plus-chatbot-component></plus-chatbot-component> 
</body>
</html>
```

But in .pug its a little bit different, the javascript and the component have to be in HEAD no need to put it in BODY

This is a sample installation that SUCCEED in page number1 (after changing it from html to follow .pub format):

```
doctype html
head
  title= title
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  script(src='https://opnge.com/vue')
  script(src='https://my-chatbot-prod.firebaseapp.com/my-chatbot-component.min.js')
  plus-chatbot-component

body
```

So I tried to use the same method on another page (page number2). But ist error this time. On this page the code a bit different. I can't find the head area. I just found the body area. so I paste the same method above the body but error come out. The code as below:

```
extends ../layout
append styles
  //-link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/customer/customer.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/customer/login.css')
  style.

script(src='https://opnge.com/vue')
  script(src='https://my-chatbot-prod.firebaseapp.com/my-chatbot-component.min.js')
  my-chatbot-component

block body
  .bg-login.segment(style='background-image: url('+background_url+')')
    include ../header_customer
```

The error come out like this:

```
Error: /home/crmroot/app-roro-jonggrang-v/views/customer/login.pug:7:1

Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template
    at makeError (/home/crmroot/app-roro-jonggrang-v/node_modules/pug-error/index.js:32:13)
    at error (/home/crmroot/app-roro-jonggrang-v/node_modules/pug-linker/index.js:7:30)
    at addNode (/home/crmroot/app-roro-jonggrang-v/node_modules/pug-linker/index.js:34:9)
```

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: As you can see in the example, the `plus-chatbot-component` element needs to go inside the `body` tag, not the `head` tag

Comment: @Sean thanks for your comment. In html yeas. have to put in body. but in pug file i has to be in head. as you can see on my second example that i have successfully install it in pug file and the component is in head. The error is in another pug file even i apply the same method as the first pug file. that is at my landing page

Comment: It has to be in the `body` in Pug too.

Comment: tried. and its error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use that widget, the javascript must be included in the `head`, and the component element must be used in the `body`.

To add the script to the `head` and the component to the `body`, you can modify your example Pug file like so:

```
doctype html
head
  title= title
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  script(src='https://opnge.com/vue')
  script(src='https://my-chatbot-prod.firebaseapp.com/my-chatbot-component.min.js')

body
  my-chatbot-component
```

In your other example, because that file is extending another file, the only statements you can have at the base indentation level of the file are `extends` and `block` (or `append` or `prepend`) statements. You can't put script elements at the base level.

You should include the `script` tag in your `layout` file, and then modify this other file to put the component in the `body`, like so:

```
extends ../layout

append styles
  //-link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/customer/customer.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/customer/login.css')

block body
  my-chatbot-component
  .bg-login.segment(style='background-image: url('+background_url+')')
    include ../header_customer
```

Comment: But could you please explain to me why on my landing page. I put the script and the component together in the head but its worked! don't have error even I don't put the component in the body?

Comment: It generates valid markup, which is why there is no error. But the component is not intended to be placed in the `head`.